# C++ rest based web service client implementation

Tags: c++, json, web-services, rest, compression

I have a requirement where I have to implement a timer based application which will periodically call a rest web service implemented in asp.net MVC 3 and store the response JSON data in a SQL Lite database. It will also have to implement a http web client to download media files of huge size which will need decompression. This component has to be written using C++.

Would need some help in isolating the logical task breakdown for this component. Typically a list of items like:

- POC to isolate an open source C++ web service communication library
- POC to isolate an open source C++ JSON framework
- POC to isolate an open source C++ Zlib packages

Also if somebody can provide some good suggestions around some stable and flexible open source libraries in C++ for

- Web Service communication
- JSON parsing
- SQL Lite adapter
- Some other lightweight database alternative to SQL Lite
- HTTP based downloader. Possibly implementing multithreaded and multipart download
- Decompression library

Performance is a primary concern for the application. can somebody suggest designs around implementing faster downloads of huge media files over HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

- [Facebook Folly](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/Overview.md) provides JSON services, amongst other utilities.
- Although not Open Source, Microsoft's [Casablanca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/casablanca.aspx) library
  provides Web Client functions.